# Composer upgrade to 9.4.x fails, my site is stuck on 9.3.x

Tags: composer

My Drupal 9 site is stuck on the 9.3.x track, I cannot upgrade to 9.4.x. If I use the standard upgrade command:

```
composer update "drupal/core-*" --with-all-dependencies
```

Then it upgrades to the latest 9.3 version (currently 9.3.22), but no further.

If I try to force to 9.4.7 (or any 9.4.x version) with:

```
composer require drupal/core-recommended:9.4.7 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:9.4.7 drupal/core-project-message:9.4.7 --update-with-all-dependencies
```

This fails with the composer error

> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended 9.4.7 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[9.4.7].
> - drupal/core-recommended 9.4.7 requires drupal/core 9.4.7 -> found drupal/core[9.4.7] but these were not loaded, likely because it
> conflicts with another require.

If I try to find out why:

```
composer prohibits drupal/core 9.4.7
```

then I get:

> drupal/core-recommended  9.3.22   requires drupal/core (9.3.22)
>
> drupal/mysql56           1.3.0    requires drupal/core (~9.0.0-beta3
> || 9.1.* || 9.2.* || 9.3.*)
>
> drupal/core 9.4.7    requires symfony/polyfill-iconv (^1.25)
>
> drupal/legacy-project    dev-main does not require
> symfony/polyfill-iconv (but v1.23.0 is installed)
>
> drupal/core              9.4.7    requires symfony/polyfill-php80
> (^1.25)
>
> drupal/legacy-project    dev-main does not require
> symfony/polyfill-php80 (but v1.23.1 is installed)
>
> drupal/core              9.4.7    requires laminas/laminas-feed
> (^2.17)
>
> drupal/legacy-project    dev-main  does not require
> laminas/laminas-feed (but 2.15.0 is installed)
>
> drupal/core              9.4.7    requires egulias/email-validator
> (^2.1.22|^3.2)
>
> drupal/legacy-project    dev-main does not require
> egulias/email-validator (but 3.1.2 is installed)
>
> drupal/core              9.4.7    requires composer/semver (^3.3)
>
> drupal/legacy-project    dev-main does not require composer/semver
> (but 3.2.6 is installed)

Should I also include all these in the composer statement? I have tried:

```
lando composer require drupal/core-recommended:9.4.7 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:9.4.7 drupal/core-project-message:9.4.7 symfony/polyfill-iconv laminas/laminas-feed egulias/email-validator composer/semver --update-with-all-dependencies
```

But this gives similar Problem 1 as before.

Any help much appreciated.

As requested, here is the composer.json file in full:

```
{
    "name": "drupal/legacy-project",
    "description": "Project template for Drupal 9 projects with composer following drupal/drupal layout",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0-or-later",
    "homepage": "https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal",
    "support": {
        "docs": "https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
        "chat": "https://www.drupal.org/node/314178"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.9",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.7",
        "drupal/administerusersbyrole": "^3.2",
        "drupal/anchor_link": "^2.5",
        "drupal/autologout": "^1.4",
        "drupal/ckeditor_resize": "^1.3",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^9.3",
        "drupal/core-project-message": "^9.3",
        "drupal/core-recommended": "^9.3",
        "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": "^9.3",
        "drupal/csv_serialization": "^2.1",
        "drupal/ctools": "^3.11",
        "drupal/embed": "^1.6",
        "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.8",
        "drupal/entityreference_filter": "^1.4",
        "drupal/field_group": "^3.3",
        "drupal/field_permissions": "^1.2",
        "drupal/google_analytics": "^3.1",
        "drupal/insert_view": "^2.0",
        "drupal/juicebox": "^3.0@alpha",
        "drupal/linkit": "^5.0@beta",
        "drupal/login_history": "^1.1",
        "drupal/mail_login": "^2.6",
        "drupal/media_directories": "^2.0",
        "drupal/media_library_edit": "^2.3",
        "drupal/menu_breadcrumb": "^1.16",
        "drupal/menu_position": "1.x-dev",
        "drupal/mysql56": "^1.3",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.11",
        "drupal/redirect": "^1.8",
        "drupal/role_watchdog": "^2.0",
        "drupal/roleassign": "^1.0@beta",
        "drupal/security_review": "^1.0@alpha",
        "drupal/tabtamer": "2.x-dev@dev",
        "drupal/token": "^1.11",
        "drupal/token_filter": "^1.4",
        "drupal/views_data_export": "^1.1",
        "drupal/webform": "^6.1",
        "drush/drush": "^11.0",
        "mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf": "~2.1",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf": "~6"
    },
    "conflict": {
        "drupal/drupal": "*"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "config": {
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "composer/installers": true,
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
            "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
            "drupal/core-project-message": true,
            "drupal/core-vendor-hardening": true
        },
        "process-timeout": 0
    },
    "extra": {
        "drupal-scaffold": {
            "locations": {
                "web-root": "./"
            }
        },
        "installer-paths": {
            "core": [
                "type:drupal-core"
            ],
            "libraries/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-library"
            ],
            "modules/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-module"
            ],
            "profiles/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-profile"
            ],
            "themes/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-theme"
            ],
            "drush/Commands/contrib/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-drush"
            ],
            "modules/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-module"
            ],
            "profiles/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-profile"
            ],
            "themes/custom/{$name}": [
                "type:drupal-custom-theme"
            ]
        },
        "drupal-core-project-message": {
            "include-keys": [
                "homepage",
                "support"
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd-message": [
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  Congratulations, you’ve installed the Drupal codebase  </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>  from the drupal/legacy-project template!               </>",
                "<bg=blue;fg=white>                                                         </>",
                "",
                "<bg=yellow;fg=black>Next steps</>:",
                "  * Install the site: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install",
                "  * Read the user guide: https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html",
                "  * Get support: https://www.drupal.org/support",
                "  * Get involved with the Drupal community:",
                "      https://www.drupal.org/getting-involved",
                "  * Remove the plugin that prints this message:",
                "      composer remove drupal/core-project-message"
            ]
        },
        "enable-patching": true,
        "patches": {
            "drupal/core": {
                "Arbitrary sizing of media - images for CKEditor: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3132211": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2021-12-08/3132211_drupal_media_ckeditor_resize_17.patch"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very difficult to provide package manager support without seeing the configuration file. Please also include the composer.json file in your question.

Comment: I have received -2 votes, I don't understand why, so please help me to improve my question (as cilefen did), happy to provide whatever additional information is needed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause appears to be:

```
drupal/mysql56 1.3.0 requires drupal/core (~9.0.0-beta3 || 9.1.* || 9.2.* || 9.3.*)
```

That unsupported version of `drupal/mysql56` does not allow Drupal 9.4 or higher.

Comment: Many thanks cilefen for helping me understand this message. I used the following command and it successfully upgraded:

lando composer require drupal/core-recommended:9.4.7 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:9.4.7 drupal/core-project-message:9.4.7 drupal/mysql56 --update-with-all-dependencies